# How to make one column a two-column format

Tags: two-column, wiley-article

Does anybody have any idea how can I do this specifically for this template below?

```
\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\title{This is the sample article title\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\author[1]{Author One*}

\author[2,3]{Author Two}

\author[3]{Author Three}

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}


\address[1]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org Name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[2]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org Name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[3]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org Name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\corres{*Corresponding author name, This is sample corresponding address. \email{authorone@gmail.com}}

\presentaddress{This is sample for present address text this is sample for present address text}


\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4}

\jnlcitation{\cname{%
\author{Williams K.},
\author{B. Hoskins},
\author{R. Lee},
\author{G. Masato}, and
\author{T. Woollings}} (\cyear{2016}),
\ctitle{A regime analysis of Atlantic winter jet variability applied to evaluate HadGEM3-GC2}, \cjournal{Q.J.R. Meteorol. Soc.}, \cvol{2017;00:1--6}.}

\maketitle

\footnotetext{\textbf{Abbreviations:} ANA, anti-nuclear antibodies; APC, antigen-presenting cells; IRF, interferon regulatory factor}


\section{Sample for first level head}\label{sec1}
\end{eqnarray}

\section{Sample for another first level head}\label{sec2}


Example for bibliography citations cite~\citep{Elbaum2002}, cites~\cite{Allen2011,Yoo2007}




\subsection{Example for second level head}


\section{Sample for next first level head}\label{sec3}

\subsection{Example for another second level head}


malesuada, diam id pretium elementum, eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed wisi.





\paragraph{Fourth level head text}



\subparagraph{Fifth level head text}


\begin{center}
\begin{table*}[t]%
\caption{This is sample table caption.\label{tab1}}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{1}}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{2}}} \\\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
\textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{col4 head}}  & \textbf{col5 head}   \\
\midrule
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 12.34  & col5 text\tnote{1}   \\
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 1.62  & col5 text\tnote{2}   \\
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 51.809  & col5 text   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}%%[341pt]
\item Source: Example for table source text.
\item[1] Example for a first table footnote.
\item[2] Example for a second table footnote.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{table}[t]%
\centering
\caption{This is sample table caption.\label{tab2}}%
\begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
\textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \textbf{col4 head}  & \textbf{col5 head} \\
\midrule
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\dagger$}   \\
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text   \\
col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\ddagger$}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Source: Example for table source text.
\item[$\dagger$] Example for a first table footnote.
\item[$\ddagger$] Example for a second table footnote.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Sorry: What's the difference to a 3-column layout? // Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: I believe that I have an uptodate LaTeX install but it knows nothing about the `WileyNJD-2` class. Where does it come from?

Comment: BTW, table and table* ignore center.  All it does is add vertical space somewhere else in the document.

Comment: @  Peter Wilson wiley template sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1** The `WileyNJD-2` class is based on the `article` class with the `onecolumn` option. Loads the `multicol` package, so it allows you to use `\begin{multicols}{2}` ... `\end{multicols}` to have a two-column document while still using the option STIX1COL.

The spacing between columns could be set using `\setlength{\columnsep}{<length>}` (15pt in the example)

Text wide tables should go on a separate page.

To use the APA option you need to add `NJDapacite.sty` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabbiocrux/Climatelabs-paper/main/NJDapacite.sty) and `WileyNJD-APA.bst`, the later to be found in the sub-directory  "Additional Template files" included in the distribution.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom   

\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt} % set columns separation <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\title{This is the sample article title\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\author[1]{Author One*}

\author[2,3]{Author Two}

\author[3]{Author Three}

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}
    
\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}
    
\address[1]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[2]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[3]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\corres{*Corresponding author name, Corresponding address. \email{authorone@Email.com}}

\presentaddress{Present address}

\abstract[Abstract]{This paper describes the use of the \LaTeXe\ \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls}
class file for setting papers for \emph{Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences}.}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4}

\jnlcitation{\cname{%
        \author{Williams K.},
        \author{B. Hoskins},
        \author{R. Lee},
        \author{G. Masato}, and
        \author{T. Woollings}} (\cyear{2016}),
    \ctitle{A regime analysis of Atlantic winter jet variability applied to evaluate HadGEM3-GC2}, \cjournal{Q.J.R. Meteorol. Soc.}, \cvol{2017;00:1--6}.}
\maketitle

\footnotetext{\textbf{Abbreviations:} ANA, anti-nuclear antibodies; APC, antigen-presenting cells; IRF, interferon regulatory factor}

\begin{multicols}{2} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

Many authors submitting \( \sin \cos \tan \inf_{x} \) to NJD journals use \LaTeXe\ to
prepare their papers. This paper describes the
\textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file which can be used to convert
articles produced with other \LaTeXe\ class files into the correct
form for publication in \emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

The \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file preserves much of the standard
\LaTeXe\ interface so that any document which was produced using
the standard \LaTeXe\ \textsf{article} style can easily be
converted to work with the \textsf{WileyNJD-v2} style. However, the
width of text and typesize will vary from that of
\textsf{article.cls}; therefore, \emph{line breaks will change}
and it is likely that displayed mathematics and tabular material
will need re-setting.

In the following sections we describe how to lay out your code to
use \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} to reproduce the typographical look of
\emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

\section{Sample for next first level head}\label{sec3}

\subsection{Example for another second level head}

malesuada, diam id pretium elementum, eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed wisi.

\paragraph{Fourth level head text}

Some text

\subparagraph{Fifth level head text}

Some text

\end{multicols}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\clearpage

\begin{table*}[ht!]%
    \caption{This is sample table caption 1.\label{tab1}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{1}}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{2}}} \\\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        \textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{col4 head}}  & \textbf{col5 head}   \\
        \midrule
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 12.34  & col5 text\tnote{1}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 1.62  & col5 text\tnote{2}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 51.809  & col5 text   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}%%[341pt]
        \item Source: Example for table source text.
        \item[1] Example for a first table footnote.
        \item[2] Example for a second table footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}


\begin{table}[ht!]%
    \centering
    \caption{This is sample table caption 2.\label{tab2}}%
    \begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \textbf{col4 head}  & \textbf{col5 head} \\
        \midrule
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\dagger$}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\ddagger$}   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item Source: Example for table source text.
        \item[$\dagger$] Example for a first table footnote.
        \item[$\ddagger$] Example for a second table footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

**OPTION 2** Instead of using STIX1COL and then creating a two-column document, you can use the STIX2COL option to make a two-column document directly.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[APA,STIX2COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
    
\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title{This is the sample article title\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\author[1]{Author One*}

\author[2,3]{Author Two}

\author[3]{Author Three}

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}  

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}
    
\address[1]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[2]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\address[3]{\orgdiv{Org Division}, \orgname{Org name}, \orgaddress{\state{State name}, \country{Country name}}}

\corres{*Corresponding author name, Corresponding address. \email{authorone@Email.com}}

\presentaddress{Present address}

\abstract[Abstract]{This paper describes the use of the \LaTeXe\ \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls}
class file for setting papers for \emph{Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences}.}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4}

\jnlcitation{\cname{%
        \author{Williams K.},
        \author{B. Hoskins},
        \author{R. Lee},
        \author{G. Masato}, and
        \author{T. Woollings}} (\cyear{2016}),
    \ctitle{A regime analysis of Atlantic winter jet variability applied to evaluate HadGEM3-GC2}, \cjournal{Q.J.R. Meteorol. Soc.}, \cvol{2017;00:1--6}.}
\maketitle

\footnotetext{\textbf{Abbreviations:} ANA, anti-nuclear antibodies; APC, antigen-presenting cells; IRF, interferon regulatory factor}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

Many authors submitting \( \sin \cos \tan \inf_{x} \) to NJD journals use \LaTeXe\ to
prepare their papers. This paper describes the
\textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file which can be used to convert
articles produced with other \LaTeXe\ class files into the correct
form for publication in \emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

The \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} class file preserves much of the standard
\LaTeXe\ interface so that any document which was produced using
the standard \LaTeXe\ \textsf{article} style can easily be
converted to work with the \textsf{WileyNJD-v2} style. However, the
width of text and typesize will vary from that of
\textsf{article.cls}; therefore, \emph{line breaks will change}
and it is likely that displayed mathematics and tabular material
will need re-setting.

In the following sections we describe how to lay out your code to
use \textsf{WileyNJD-v2.cls} to reproduce the typographical look of
\emph{Wiley NJD Journals}.

\section{Sample for next first level head}\label{sec3}
    
\subsection{Example for another second level head}

malesuada, diam id pretium elementum, eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed wisi.

\paragraph{Fourth level head text}

Some text

\subparagraph{Fifth level head text}

Some text

\section{Results}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in  themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms  of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic   of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section,   reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{table*}[ht!]%
    \caption{This is sample table caption 1.\label{tab1}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{1}}} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Spanned heading\tnote{2}}} \\\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
        \textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{col4 head}}  & \textbf{col5 head}   \\
        \midrule
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 12.34  & col5 text\tnote{1}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 1.62  & col5 text\tnote{2}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & 51.809  & col5 text   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}%%[341pt]
        \item Source: Example for table source text.
        \item[1] Example for a first table footnote.
        \item[2] Example for a second table footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}
    
\begin{table}[ht!]%
    \centering
    \caption{This is sample table caption 2.\label{tab2}}%
    \begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{col1 head} & \textbf{col2 head}  & \textbf{col3 head}  & \textbf{col4 head}  & \textbf{col5 head} \\
        \midrule
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\dagger$}   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text   \\
        col1 text & col2 text  & col3 text  & col4 text  & col5 text\tnote{$\ddagger$}   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item Source: Example for table source text.
        \item[$\dagger$] Example for a first table footnote.
        \item[$\ddagger$] Example for a second table footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Comment: Really thank you very much.

Comment: sorry. Should the citations like this?@Article{Rothermel1997,
      author = "Rothermel, G.",
       title = "A safe efficient regression test selection technique",
     journal = "ACM {T}ransactions on {S}oftware {E}ngineering and {M}ethodology",
        year = "1997",
      volume = "6",
      number = "2",
       pages = "173--210"

Comment: @ Simon Dispa sorry I have problem with citation. How should I put my citation in .bib file. I had previously for elsevier bibtex but this is different. I just normally copy from bibtex in scholar but for this one i dont know what to do

Comment: Also I have problem in fugure. Figures are not appeared!

Comment: @Ahmad Turani This site works best with one question at a time. For the benefit of other users, please ask additional questions, with the appropriate tags.

Comment: @Ahmad Turani Regarding figures, if you are allowed to change STIX1COL to STIX2COL, use this option. See the second example of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much